# can't apply process slot

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi

I've got a problem with a webserver. I did change nothing on the Apache config, I was just working on the site (typo3 FYI) when I got these 500 Error codes. Other websites are running fine. Could it be that it was a one-time error and apache then decided "I dont like you anymore"?

```
[Tue May 03 15:44:47 2011] [warn] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: read data from fastcgi server error.
[Tue May 03 16:00:02 2011] [warn] mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /home/<customer>/public_html/typo3/ajax.php
[Tue May 03 16:00:08 2011] [warn] mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /home/<customer>/public_html/index.php
[Tue May 03 16:00:38 2011] [warn] mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /home/<customer>/public_html/index.php
[Tue May 03 16:00:42 2011] [warn] mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /home/<customer>/public_html/index.php
[Tue May 03 16:01:00 2011] [warn] mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /home/<customer>/public_html/index.php
and so on...
```

my fcgid.conf

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
  MaxProcessCount 100
  AddHandler    fcgid-script .fcgi
  IPCConnectTimeout 20
</IfModule>
```

would restart the (production-)server solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

But It appears the maxProcessCount rule is not honored found here 
http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=2563

If you read that you see you can set a variable to ensure it does

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://www.megalinux.net/mod_fcgid-cant-apply-process-slot/) page:

> The fix is simple. In my case it was a
>   simple chmod 755 /var/log/httpd, which
>   allows Apache to actually read its log
>   directory! Before the change, I was
>   getting “Service Unavailable” with a
>   log error of [warn] mod_fcgid: can’t
>   apply process slot for [dispatch.fcgi
>   full path]. Now it works!

Comment: well, I guess thats the default directory where apache logs to, But we're using virtualmin, so its /var/log/virtualmin/ which is set to 777 (dont worry, the files have better permissions), So that shouldnt be the problem